# Is a linear mixed model appropriate to test 16 single, but nested pictures

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model, methodology

as a pre-study, I want to let participants rate Likert scales for 16 pictures.

These 16 pictures are nested as following: We took 4 photographs of 2 male and 2 female doctors, each assumed the exact same 2 open and 2 closed postures ((2+2)*(2+2)=16).

We want to show, that there is no difference between the 2 male doctors. The same for the female doctors, and for the 2 closed and the 2 open postures.

For the main study we want to use these pictures to show differences between male and female doctors and closed and open postures.

I'm not sure, which method to use.

I think about to use a linear mixed model:
Independent Variable: picture (nominalscale, with 16 single picture)
I want to include single_person, single_posture and proband_id (each proband rates all participants) as mixed variables
Dependent variable would be the Likert scale items.

Would be this a legit approach?

Comment: What are the random effects here ?

Comment: @RobertLong The random effects are single_person, single posture, and proband_id. Thank you for commenting. We want to make sure, the main study will find the differences between male and female doctors and not male_doctor1 and the other 
persons.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the study design. How are single_person, single posture, and proband_id related to each other, and how are they related to "4 photographs of 2 male and 2 female doctors, each assumed the exact same 2 open and 2 closed postures". Also, what is the actual model formula that you are intending to use ? Finally, how many of each random effect grouping variables are there ?